# How to get code navigation features working in VSCode for Apex?

Tags: salesforce, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode to work with my salesforce sandbox and would like to edit Apex code in VSCode.
I want to know how I can activate features like "Jump to definition" / "Go to documentation" etc in VSCode for Apex.

I have installed the following extensions:

1. Apex
2. ForceCode
3. Salesforce CLI Integration
4. Salesforce Extension Pack
5. Visualforce

Intellisense works. Command+Click does not.